# Clojure perform map function on array elements

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I've defined persons like this

```
(def persons 
  '({:id 1 :name "olle"} 
    {:id 2 :name "anna"} 
    {:id 3 :name "isak"} 
    {:id 4 :name "beatrice"}))
```

I want to map elements from persons like this command here

```
(map :id persons)
(1 2 3 4)
```

However the term :id will be within brackets like so `[:id]`. How do I cancel out the brackets so that a function in the form of

```
(map [:id] persons)
```

performs the same as

```
(map :id persons)
```

In addition it would be great if the numbers were displayed one per column with :id as the heading.

Comment: Can't you just take the first element of the vector to get `:id`?

Comment: Um, I think so, but I want to do it this way, this is just a toy problem.

Comment: I need something like add an at symbol infront of the square brackets or something.

Comment: There's no way to have those 2 expressions be equal. You need to process the vector before giving it to `map`. And what if there's more than 1 key in the vector? What do you expect the result to be? And show what you've already tried, and describe what specifically the problem you're having is. This is very broad right now.

Comment: Ok, that will take me a few minutes. What do you mena by process the vector? Could you give an example of this please?

Comment: Like `(map (first [:id]) persons)`, which "processes" the vector using `first`. You can't just give the key vector to `map` and try to use it like you're trying to.

Comment: It works when I do `(map :id persons)` I just want to map every element in the vector

Comment: Oh I think I know what you mean. Do you know how to do that not just on the first element but on every element?

Comment: Need more detail on this comment.... perhaps edit question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I assume that you want to extract some keys in order.  That can be done with `juxt`.  E.g.:

```
user=> (map (juxt :id :name) persons)
([1 "olle"] [2 "anna"] [3 "isak"] [4 "beatrice"])
```

Or if you really need an vector there, use `(apply juxt [:id :name])`

Answer (score 2):

```
(def persons
  '( {:id 1 :name "olle"}
     {:id 2 :name "anna"}
     {:id 3 :name "isak"}
     {:id 4 :name "beatrice"}))


(mapv (first [:id]) persons) => [1 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
(defn map' [keys records]
  (map #(select-keys % keys) records))

(map' [:id] persons);;=>({:id 1} {:id 2} {:id 3} {:id 4})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the data structure would look like this one?

```
(def persons 
  '({[:id] 1 :name "olle"} 
    {[:id] 2 :name "anna"} 
    {[:id] 3 :name "isak"} 
    {[:id] 4 :name "beatrice"}))
```

If yes, this code will solve the problem:

```
user=> (mapv #(get % [:id]) persons)
[1 2 3 4]
```